# SVN development and production versions on same server

Tags: git, svn

It's not easy to explain what my needs are, therefore it's hard to google for things you can't explain in three keywords.

So what is that I need? I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server where my clients homepage will sit. They demand a lot of upgrades so it is hard to copy files from my own development server to client server. I would like to install SVN on client server, where:
- development version will sit under dev.client.com
- production version will sit under client.com
(different folders on the same server)

So, when I'm developing something, the changes made are visible on restricted area - dev.client.com. But they do not appear on client.com until I have committed them.

As I understand, SVN usually works with your local machine, but I don't want to let development version to stay on my local computer.

So, if you understood my needs, can you help me or show some useful direction please? :)

Comment: Git or SVN??? Make your choice before I'll spent own time for nothing

Comment: Read it carefully and try to pay attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've mentioned `git` in the taglist, I assume that you don't mind to use it instead of `svn` :) . So I would propose a following workflow.

The first area is a computer (or even computers) where you perform development. It's your own playground and you're free to do there anything you want. There's also a development installation of your product (a folder on a hosting or whatever). It's where your customers evaluate "beta-versions". And the third entity is production code (again, a folder on a hosting or whatever).

First of all you create a [private] `git`-repository on your computer. Also you need to create a "bare" repository on the hosting to publish your project in `dev.client.com` and `client.com` (or two repositories, if "beta" and "production" areas are on different hosts). Use `git init --bare` for this.

Then you depelop your code as usually. You're free to make anything you want there: change files, make commits, amend them, move back and forth in the history etc. Just don't remember commit your changes :-) Don't worry they're stored locally :)

Whenever you think you created something worth publishing on `dev.client.com`, you choose an appropriate commit and [`tag`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) it as e.g. `beta/v1.2.3.1234`. If you think you've created something worth publishing in th production area, you `tag` it as e.g. `rel/v1.2.3`. Then you [`push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) required tags into the hosting repository (or repositories).

Now the changes are there, but they're still "packed" into the repository, not visible n the filesystem. You need to [`check out`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) them.

You may simply login to the hosting and manually run a command like this:

```
cd /path/to/dev.client.com/dir/
GIT_DIR=/path/to/repository GIT_WORK_DIR=. git checkout beta/v1.2.3.1234
cd /path/to/client.com/dir/
GIT_DIR=/path/to/repository GIT_WORK_DIR=. git checkout rel/v1.2.3
```

These steps can be automated. There's [`post-receive` git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) which runs on the hosting site whenever someone pushes there some commits and references.